# Changing Global Cabal Flags from the Command Line with Stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

From a project's cabal file:

```
flag buildAll
  Description: Build all programs
  Default:     False
```

I wanted to set this to true from the `stack build <executable>` perspective. I tried using `--flag buildAll` and it didn't work. Must you change this from `False` to `True` within the cabal file, or is there a way to change the flag from the command line?

Comment: Does this work: `stack build pkgname --flag pkgname:buildAll` ?

Comment: Have you tried: `--force-dirty`? to force rebuild of packages even when it doesn't seem necessary based on file dirtiness.